# Need Database Design for the Scenario

Tags: database-design

I have bumped into a problem while designing my application database. I have searched the web for a similar structure but was unable to find any. So here is the question:

I have a page designed with the search page and the data grid.see the screen shot below:

[image: The scenario when the first identity is chosen]

I have a table called **contact** that have a relationship with the identity and it's sub type.

The Identity type holds just two values for now but may increase in future (Parking, living area), based on the item selected in the dropdown, the search fields are changed and so does the-the grid view with it (see headers). The first image shows that when identity type parking is selected then the user can filter the results by section, lane, row and the parking number.

[image: The scenario when the first identity is chosen]

If we change the Identity Type the search fields are changed again with the **Row** field being the same in both the identity types.

The user should have the ability to save the details selected from the grid for a contact (in the contact table) in the database.

I am confused how should I design a database that will show the grid with the fields for identities and these identities than can be saved to the database with a relation to the contact.

Here is something that I came up with

[image: Database Schema]

I am still not clear on how will the selected rows will be saved in the database.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to change your approach somewhat. First of all, you should design the database that contains your business data, without worry about how you save things like the state of the search dialog. Including these at this point will just confuse the design.

The diagram you give looks good. You should just remove the table 'IdentityType'. This is not a good table - it contains two completely different types of thing. This is always a clue that something is wrong in a SQL database. Whereas in OO we might have two classes `ContactIdentity` and `BuildingIdentity` which inherit from a common base class or interface, this is not the right way to do it in SQL.

Now, you should be able to make each of the search pages work in Javascript. Try to do so, forgetting that you want a 'general case' solution that works for different sets of columns. You have two remaining problems it seems:

- If you add a new identity, you want to be able to do so 'in configuration', by changing some data rather than writing new code.
- You want to be able to save a user's searches, possibly (but not necessarily) in the same database.

The first is a question of how you design your application. You shouldn't expect that the interface will exactly reflect the database structure. You could have many more database tables, and still have the same two search methods. Or you could have further search methods, still using the same tables you have currently. Either way, you should be wary of trying to automatically generate the search pages from the structure of your database tables. Rather choose the 'views' that you might use, and find a good way of representing their metadata. This could be for example, a list of columns which can be filtered/sorted on. Or the text of the SQL query which retrieves all the items you want to have in your table.

Secondly, you want to save the search. There are two ways you can do this - do you want to save the parameters of the search (so that the same filtering/sorting can be run again a different time, on possibly changed data, and show up-to-date results? Or do you want to save the results so that the user can see exactly the set of entries that they found that time?

I tend to think the first makes more sense, because it means that they are not seeing something which might be out-of-date. If this is the case, I would try and store details of all the filters, etc. in something like a JSON object. (You could also use XML - I tend to think JSON is much easier to work with.) In JSON in might look something like this:

```
{
  "query": "parking",
  "filters": {
    "section": "A",
    "lane": [1, 2, 5, 6],
    "row_number": {
      "greater_than": 10
    },
  },
  "selected": [1,2 3, 4]
}
```

Now, you can save the JSON document in a database which doesn't have to be, but could be, the same as the one which you keep the parking data in. You could equally store it in something like a document database. You want to have in that database, data which pertains to the use of the app and the queries, things like the user who saved the search, the session id, the timestamp it was saved, and so on. In this method, don't worry about linking up the search to exactly the set of data which was there when the search was made.

The other approach is to save all the identifiers from the rows which were selected when the search was made. I think this is a little more problematic. What if the identifiers in the database change, and the row which the right ID no longer has the rest of the details correct? What if someone choose an entry because it was on a given floor of a given building, and now it's not anymore?

Anyway, in this case, if you are certain that the identifiers still refer to the same data, you might just want to save a list of IDs. The way to do it in SQL is probably like this: you create a table saved_search with the user id, time saved and so on. Then you create two 'association tables':

```
CREATE TABLE saved_search_parking
(
  saved_search_id int,
  parking_id int,
  CONSTRAINT uc_saved_search_parking UNIQUE (saved_search_id, parking_id)
)
```

and a similar table `saved_search_living_area`. For each parking in a saved search, you create a row in the table, which links them. One saved search contains multiple parkings and one parking can be contained in multiple saved searches. This does mean that you can have both parkings and living areas in a saved search. But this is, I think, a small drawback compared to alternative designs. In any case, code which loads a saved search into the 'parking' page should only look at the `saved_search_parking` table, and same with the 'living area' page.

Answer (score -1):

Your filter needs to run a make-table query that will save the results in a new table. Then you can send the results to a report or an email depending on what you want. The key is the make-table query.

Comment: eww no, please don't dynamically create tables for stuff like this